# ROS/Gazebo crashes when spawing PR2 robot model

Tags: ros, gazebo, pr2-simulator, pr2, pr2-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all.
I am new to ROS and also to this mailing group, so let me introduce myself breifly:

I am a student in Computer Vision and Robotics and currently working on my master's thesis which needs to be carried out in ROS.
I am getting really strange errors when running GAZEBO and spawing a PR2. In fact the entire GAZEBO crashes and I do not know how to track this error.

Here is the error message I get:

```
[ WARN] [1329924386.489855153, 11.500000000]: You've passed in true for auto_start for the C++ action server at [/head_traj_controller/follow_joint_trajectory]. You should always pass in false to avoid race conditions.
[base_laser_self_filter-23] process has finished cleanly.
log file: /home/reinhard/.ros/log/9799641e-5d66-11e1-8c07-485b39b465c6/base_laser_self_filter-23*.log
respawning...
[base_laser_self_filter-23] restarting process
process[base_laser_self_filter-23]: started with pid [17328]
[ WARN] [1329924386.592470362, 11.506000000]: Shutdown request received.
[ WARN] [1329924386.592511749, 11.506000000]: Reason given for shutdown: [new node registered with same name]
[ WARN] [1329924386.756356578, 11.529000000]: no localization information yet (odom_combined -> base_laser_link)
[ WARN] [1329924386.928924445, 11.546000000]: No collision geometry specified for link 'r_forearm_cam_frame'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/scripts/spawner", line 159, in <module>
if __name__ == '__main__': main()
File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/scripts/spawner", line 137, in main
resp = load_controller(name)
File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/src/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 430, in __call__
return self.call(*args, **kwds)
File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/src/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 519, in call
raise ServiceException("transport error completing service call: %s"%(str(e)))
rospy.service.ServiceException: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
[gazebo-1] process has died [pid 11286, exit code -11].
log files: /home/reinhard/.ros/log/9799641e-5d66-11e1-8c07-485b39b465c6/gazebo-1*.log
[tilt_laser_self_filter-21] process has finished cleanly.
log file: /home/reinhard/.ros/log/9799641e-5d66-11e1-8c07-485b39b465c6/tilt_laser_self_filter-21*.log
```

It seems that if I launch it with gdb it works, but it is extremely weird and definitely not a permanent solution. But I do not know any other way to fix this ..

I hope someone can help me in this. Thank you all in advance!

Best,
Reinhard

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28253/ros/gazebo-crashes-when-spawing-pr2-robot-model/) by [ReiniK](https://answers.ros.org/users/1841/reinik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 84 on 2012-02-22

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-02-23**:
are you: 1. roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch 2. roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2.launch and 3. seeing this crash?  is the error message from the first roslaunch console?  and can you try attaching gdb to gazebo thread after step 1 and see if you can catch this segfault that way?  thanks.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-03-14**:
Same problem here. "roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch" leads to a crash in gazebo. The mentioned log file does not exist. Running first 1 and then 2 will kill gazebo in 1 as soon as 2 starts up (exit code -11), and then kill default_controllers_spawner (exit code 1).

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-03-14**:
This happened with the latest ROS electric on two different machines with NVidia graphics card, one Core i7 with Ubuntu 11.10 and one Core i5 with Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

please see my post about nvidia driver in this [question](http://answers.ros.org/question/30105/gazebo-dies-when-openning-with-pr2-controller?answer=30302#post-id-30302), check & downgrade if you have 295.* drivers installed and see if that helps.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1